# ViewPager is cut off

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout, swiperefreshlayout

I have a TabLayout, below a SwipeRefreshLayout containing a ViewPager (each page has a RecyclerView). I used to have the SRL in each page fragment but now changed it so I only have one which is way more convenient. 
For some reason the ViewPager gets cut off and I'm unable to scroll all the way up to the top of the RecyclerView.

Does anyone have a solution for that?

[image]

Here are my layout xmls:
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabGravity="fill" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainSwipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mainViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainTabLayout" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/mainRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your RelativeLayout by a LinearLayout in your activity_main.

Comment: Thanks! Too obvious I didn't think about that.

Comment: Don't forget to add orientation="vertical" ;)

Comment: Thank You! I used CoordinatorLayout instead of RelativeLayout, and have same issue. But what is the reason? Maybe because we haven't declared relative positions of childs?

Comment: thank you works well simple solution